# semantic-ui layout with full screen image?

Tags: semantic-ui

I am looking at semantic-ui for the first time and I was wondering how to make a layout where an image takes the full screen no matter what the size of the screen is and then when you scroll down to see the other sections, the menu is fixed at the top.

To illustrate, here are some examples:

- http://yootheme.com/demo/themes/wordpress/2015/gusto/?style=default
- http://yootheme.com/demo/themes/wordpress/2015/venice/?style=default
- http://yootheme.com/demo/themes/wordpress/2015/helios/?style=default
- http://layoutnet.com.br/
- http://yootheme.com/demo/themes/wordpress/2015/finch/?style=default

Answer (score 2):

Go to the examples in your semantic-ui source file and open the `homepage.html` with your editor.

In the style tag and this :

```
.masthead {
        background-image: url('bg.jpg') !important;
        background-size: cover !important;
}
```

Now open the file in your browser and view the change as you wanted.